# How to filter users in azure b2c based on custom user attribute?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a custom user attribute `customerId` in Azure B2C user attributes to distinguish users of a particular customer. I can create users using [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api) and .net B2C sdk and set the customerId using this git hub [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/blob/master/src/Services/UserService.cs)

The problem I have is I can't filter customers by customerId. My code looks like below

```
    public static async Task<List<User>> GetAllB2CUsersByCustomerId(GraphServiceClient graphClient, int customerId)
    {

        try
        {
            // Get users by customerId
            var result = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Filter($"additionalData/any(c:c/key eq 'extension_b2cApplicationIdWithoutDashes_customerId' and c/value eq '{customerId}')")
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.DisplayName,
                    e.Id,
                    e.Identities
                })
                .GetAsync();

            if (result != null)
            {
                return result.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch exception

        }
        return null;
    }
```

and I get the following exception when the code runs

```
Code: BadRequest
Message: Filter not supported.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    request-id: 21d0c9d3-7d6a-4c97-9066-c99f678aec54
    date: 2020-06-10T15:59:37
ClientRequestId: 21d0c9d3-7d6a-4c97-9066-c99f678aec54
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just if it helps someone, the following syntax filters on the custom attribute

```
public static async Task<List<User>> GetAllB2CUsersByCustomerId(GraphServiceClient graphClient, int customerId)
{

    try
    {
        // Get users by customerId
        var result = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter($"extension_b2cApplicationIdWithoutDashes_customerId eq {customerId}")
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.DisplayName,
                e.Id,
                e.Identities
            })
            .GetAsync();

        if (result != null)
        {
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // catch exception

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solved my problem. Additionally I had to make sure the custom attribute did not start with a upper-case letter. As "CustomerId" would either throw an exception if filtered by lower case or not return any result if filtered by upper-case. Defining it as "customerId" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When filtering on identities, you must supply both issuer and issuerAssignedId.Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-find-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name)

```
.Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'j.smith@yahoo.com' and c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')")
```

Comment: I  have tried adding the issuer in the filter but it does not make a difference.